# May I tell someone, in the imperative, "Always be using X"?

Tags: verb-forms, progressive-aspect

I was recently criticized for the statement

> If I could offer you a piece of unsolicited advice, it would be this: Always be using the Oxford comma.

I would like to know whether this is grammatically incorrect and why.

Comment: Can you give us the entire sentence and a little bit of context?  That will help us decide if it's grammatical and appropriate in context.

Comment: "If I could offer you a piece of unsolicited advice, it would be this: always be using the Oxford comma."

Answer (score 1):

> If I could offer you a piece of unsolicited advice, it would be this: always *be using* the Oxford comma.

it is grammatical. But it sounds like, well, Indian English. If that is your dialect, you might be okay with that. In the US, UK, etc, we would say

> If I could offer you a piece of unsolicited advice, it would be this: always *use* the Oxford comma.

In general, a lot of non-native speakers (I do not know if you are one or not) overuse the progressive aspect. In addition, using the construction *be + present participle* for an imperative just sounds off (not that great) to native speakers in the US, Canada, UK, Australia...